Isn't Gaunilo's Lost Island God itself?
Sorry - I found 11 references to Gaunilo: But none of them address this. I am just starting on Norton's Introduction to philosophy and am stuck on this question.
Gaunilo counters Anselm's claim with his Lost Island refutation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaunilo_of_Marmoutiers.
But if the island is 'perfect', wouldn't that be the same as God as defined by Anselm? I can see how Gaunilo is jumping the gun in saying that the island has to exist in our ocean. But wouldn't the 'perfect' island be able to pretty much do what God can?
In other words, Is it wrong to attribute 'perfect' / 'greatest' tags only to god?

Why not directly arguing that the freedom on an even perfect island can still be made greater by leaving the said island and levitating to an all-encompassing realm, therefore a 'perfect' island is not truly perfect, it's just said to be 'perfect' in the narrow sense of all possible islands only?...

Anselm's reply was also pretty much that the island must be God.
But the ontological argument is fallacious because it picks definitions so as to assume its conclusion (by defining God as maximally great and defining maximal greatness to include existence).
You can pick other definitions that would assume a different conclusion (for an equally fallacious argument).
But "great" is fuzzy enough that you can define it to mean whatever you want it to mean. So any analogous argument can arbitrarily be dismissed by simply insisting on one's own definition (that would entail maximal greatness equalling God) and rejecting any other definition. But this wouldn't tell us much about what's true.
One might imagine an argument using a different term, instead:

P1: Roland The Closet Goblin is that entity than which no more chaotic can be conceived.
P2: It is more chaotic to exist in reality than merely as an idea.
P3: If Roland does not exist, one can conceive of an even more chaotic entity, that is one that does exist.
C: Therefore, Roland exists in reality.

Believers in a maximally great god probably wouldn't say chaos boils down to greatness so wouldn't argue that this also just ends up being an argument for their god.
But I imagine they might give one or more of the following responses:

Rejecting the definition of Roland as maximally chaotic.
Rejecting the definition of maximally chaotic to include existence.
Saying "chaotic" is poorly defined.
Saying they see no good reason to think a maximally chaotic entity exists, or the universe doesn't look the way we'd expect if a maximally chaotic entity exists.
Saying something like: God's existence or greatness has already been established or supersedes Roland's existence, or greatness supercedes chaos.

Note that #1 through #4 would be just as valid as counter-arguments to the ontological argument (replacing chaotic with great and Roland with God).
Meanwhile, #5 is debatable and may yet again entail assuming one's conclusion. If your best counter-argument to Roland (or any other hypothetical maximal being) is that God's existence trumps it, it seems to me that something has gone very wrong in your epistemology, and you aren't interested in using logic to figure out what's true as much as you're interested in just trying to support your existing conclusion. To make for valid reasoning, one would need to formally establish a hierarchy of which maximal properties supersedes which, and, crucially, also provide a justification for said hierarchy. Although this would probably just get into more and more abstract territory and get further and further from anything we can reasonably know to be true.

Hmm - I think i am (and Anselm is) saying maximality / perfection is only attainable by god (or mathematically abstract entities). We are not debating great: We are debating 'greatest'.
So assuming Roland is the perfect goblin, wouldn't Roland be God as well? (Just like the lost island being god).
IOW - I don't understand why we would try to refute it as much as state Roland would be god of mischief. Why is this not valid reasoning?

@SubS I think maybe the objection NTG is making is more clear if we were to try and attribute properties to Roland and God. E.G. if Roland, as part of being maximally chaotic, places whoopee cushions under people's chairs, and God, being maximally great, does not demean Himself to pull pranks like that, then it's unclear whether we can reconcile them as referring to the same entity?

You can cut out the rest of the objections and the need for a reductio by noting that to deny objection 4 means asserting that exactly one maximally great (etc) entity exists, which is identical to asserting that God exists, which means that the Ontological Argument's conclusion is one of its necessary implicit premises, which means that we can shorten the Ontological Argument to "there is God therefore there is God".

@SubS "We are not debating great: We are debating 'greatest'" - you're not doing either. You're just asserting/defining what "greatest-ness" is, and that God is the greatest being. I didn't say Roland is "the perfect goblin", I merely said he's maximally chaotic (the debate as to whether this classifies as perfection would be a somewhat pointless aside). The issue with accepting that God is maximally chaotic is that it directly conflicts with the other attributes people commonly assign to God (including potentially greatness and perfection).

@NotThatGuy - why does perfection/maximal greatness conflict with maximal chaotic? The core point is maximality is God, it could be maximum chaos too.

@SubS It seems like the bullet one has to bite if god is the most-maximal anything, God is also "that which nothing more evil may be conceived", likewise "purple", "incompetent", "stinky", etc

@SubS Much like Kaia said, the problem comes in when you try to explain what maximal chaos/perfection/greatness entails, and what a being with those attributes would actually do. You either boil those properties down to a meaningless abstraction, in which case the only concrete attribute that's really included in those properties is existence, but only because it's defined as such in the argument, and the argument requires it to be so. If one considers what such a being would do, every act needs to simultaneously be maximally chaotic, maximally perfect, maximally great, which seems untenable.

Hmm - IIUC - Kaia is attaching morality to the God discussion here. I am not talking god in the christian sense, this is God in the super natural sense. So I don't know if we can add a premise that we understand his 'will' per se - to do good or evil. I also see @NotThatGuy is saying every action needs to be all those: Again this presumes the super natural being's actions are explainable by us. But thanks for engaging - I think I see how philosophical arguments go now :)
